# EF Database first - Adding database Schema to the namespace in generated code

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx

Thanks for your time in reading this.

Previously I worked in a project that auto-generated the class files with SQLMetal for Linq2Sql.
In doing so it provided the namespace to match the sql schema.

So instead of being "Model.MyClass" it produced "Model.MySchema.MyClass".

I thought this was out of the box at the time, but it appears not, or not in EF anyway.

I've traced the namespace generation down to `code.VsNamespaceSuggestion();`
but I'm not able to work out how I can inject the schema into the namespace.

I can see the schema in the edmx also.

My question is:
How do I add the schema into the namespace for the auto generated entity?

As a second question:
what is the best way to do this given the original TT might change over time via new releases.
So that I don't have to recall and redo all of the changes I make when the TT is updated.

Many Thanks in advance,
Rod